# What is wrong with this attempt at figuring out the probability of drawing a 5-card poker hand with at least one pair?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that a 5-card poker hand has at least one pair? Note that this is the same as: probability of exactly one pair + probability of exactly two pairs + probability of exactly 3 of a kind + probability of exaclty 4 of a kind.

Let us study a reduced example to help us figure out how to tackle the problem. Imagine that there are 3 balls numbered 1 to 3, coloured red, and 3 similarly numbered balls coloured black. What is the probability of picking 3 balls out of the 6 such that at least two of the balls have the same number value. There are ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ ways of picking out 3 balls from 6:
    \begin{align*}
    &R1, R2, R3 \quad B1, B2, B3 \\
    &\color{blue}{R1, R2, B1} \quad \color{blue}{R1, R2, B2} \quad R1, R2, B3 \\
    &\color{blue}{R1, R3, B1} \quad R1, R3, B2 \quad \color{blue}{R1, R3, B3} \\
    &R2, R3, B1 \quad \color{blue}{R2, R3, B2} \quad \color{blue}{R2, R3, B3} \\  
    &\color{blue}{R1, B1, B2} \quad R1, B2, B3 \quad \color{blue}{R1, B1, B3} \\
    &\color{blue}{R2, B1, B2} \quad \color{blue}{R2, B2, B3} \quad R2, B1, B3 \\
    &R3, B1, B2 \quad \color{blue}{R3, B2, B3} \quad \color{blue}{R3, B1, B3}
\end{align*}

We see through brute force that the probability of picking 3 balls where at least two balls have the same number value is $12/20 = 3/5$. Let us attempt to arrive at this answer computationally. Now, there are 6 ways from which we can make the initial selection of a ball. There is only one choice for the second ball, since it must have the same number value as the first. There are 4 balls left now, and from it we can choose any one, so there are 4 choices. Thus, in total, there $6 \times 1 \times 4$ ways of making this choice, but $6 \times 4 = 24 > 20$, so $24/20 > 1$. One could imagine that what is going wrong is that we are making subtle assumptions regarding the order in which the balls are picked! So, let's say we divided the numerator out by the number of ways in which we can arrange 3 balls, $3! = 6$; then we get $4/20 = 1/5$, which is still not the right answer.

Let us attempt to get rid of order entirely when constructing our solution. There are 3 number values from which we can pick a pair of balls. There are now 4 balls left, and out of them we can pick any ball. So, we have $3 \times 4 = 12$, and indeed $12/20 = 3/5$.

Let us apply this method to yet another case: get rid of balls $R3$ and $B3$, so our scenario only has 4 balls. What is the probability of picking two balls with the same value? Well, there are 2 number values from which we can pair of balls, but ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways we can pick a pair of balls overall, so the probability of picking two balls with the same value should be $2/6 = 1/3$. Let us verify that this is the case using brute force:
    \begin{align*}
    &R1, R2 \quad B1, B2 \\
    &\color{blue}{R1, B1} \quad R1, B2 \\
    &R2, B1 \quad \color{blue}{R2, B2}
\end{align*}
Okay, so it works here too. Another simple case is 3 colours (say, red, black and white), but only 2 values---what is the probability of picking out a pair of balls with the same number value? In this case, there are 2 choices for the value from which we can pick a pair of balls, but ${6 \choose 2}$ ways of picking out a pair of balls in general. So the answer should be $2/15$? Let us verify using brute force:
    \begin{align*}
    &R1, R2 \quad B1, B2 \quad W1, W2 \\
    &\color{blue}{R1, B1} \quad R1, B2 \\
    &\color{blue}{R1, W1} \quad R1, W2 \\
    &R2, B1 \quad \color{blue}{R2, B2} \\
    &R2, W1 \quad \color{blue}{R2, W2} \\
    &\color{blue}{B1, W1} \quad B2, W1 \\
    &B2, W1 \quad \color{blue}{B2, W2}
\end{align*}
The correct answer is actually $6/15 = 2/5$, and it seems the counting method we developed so far does not account for more than 2 colours. There are 3 ways we can pick 2 colours out of 3. There are the 2 number values. So, there are $3 \times 2 = 6$ ways of picking out a pair of balls with the same number value. Hence, the probability of picking out 2 balls with the same number value is $6/15$.

Let us apply this method then to the original problem: there are 4 suites from which we can pick 2 out of. There are 13 number values from which we can pick a pair of cards. There are now 50 cards left, so there are ${50 \choose 3}$ ways of picking out out the remaining cards. So the probability should be:
    $$\frac{{50 \choose 3} \times {13 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 2}}{{52 \choose 5}} = 0.59$$

We can no longer brute force to verify, but we can use the work of others to help us. It has been determined that the probability of drawing a hand with no interesting characteristics (i.e. only a high card) is approximately $0.5$. Since probabilities must add up to $1$, there is no way that the probability of drawing at least one pair is greater than approximately $0.5$, so our above answer is incorrect.

What is the method developed to help count in such problems missing?

Comment: Your error is that you are overcounting.  Your number $\binom{50}{3}\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ counts the hand $(A\spadesuit A\heartsuit)(A\diamondsuit 2\diamondsuit 3\diamondsuit)$ differently than $(A\spadesuit A\diamondsuit)(A\heartsuit 2\diamondsuit 3\diamondsuit)$ among other occurrences of overcounting.  You will have a much easier time to calculate exactly one pair + exactly a three of a kind + exactly two pair + exactly a full house + exactly a four of a kind.

Comment: As for your first section about the six balls and picking three of them, it isn't quite the same as the poker question since you do not have the ability to trigger the condition "I have a pair" in more than one way in the same draw.  Changing the problem to three colors and three values each, you should still be able to brute force it and you will run into the same errors in your calculations there as you do for the poker question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the compliment rule.

$P$(at least one pair) $=$ $1-P$(no pairs) $= 1-(\frac{52}{52} \cdot \frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{50} \cdot \frac{40}{49} \cdot \frac{36}{48}) = .493$

Where $\frac{52}{52}$ comes from selecting any of the $52$ cards, but then the next cannot be of that same rank, so there are only $48$ choices left of the $51$ cards remaining, etc.

Equivalently, we have,

$1-P$(no pairs) $= 1-\frac{\binom{13}{5} \binom{4}{1}^5}{52\choose{5}} = .493$

Since we are selecting $5$ of the $13$ ranks to be selected (no repeats), and $1$ of the $4$ suits of that particular rank, $5$ times.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, in all of the simplified examples, you were picking two balls, but then you jumped to picking *five* cards. Suppose you pick four balls from (R1,R2,R3,R4,B1,B2,B3,B4). There are four different pairs you can make. There will be six other balls left, of which you need to choose two. So are there 4*(6C2) ways of getting pairs? No, because this method double counts two-pairs. For instance, R1,R2,B1,B2 will be counted as R1,R2 plus two more balls, *and* it will be counted as B1,B2 plus two more balls. Whenever you add probabilities, you have to make sure that they are mutually exclusive.

The simplest way to do this is, rather than trying to find the probability of getting a pair, finding the probability of getting no pair, and then subtracting that number from one. The probability that you don't have a pair after you've drawn one card is 1 (there is no way to get a pair from one card). The probability of the next card not making a pair is 48/51 (there are 51 cards remaining, of which 48 don't match that card). The next card is 44/50, then 40/49, 36/48. So the probability of getting a pair is 1-(48/51)(44/50)(40/49)(36/48). Another way of thinking about it is that there are 13 card values, and you have to take 5 different values, giving 13C5 possibilities. Within each value, there are 4 suits, so there are (13C5)*4<sup>5</sup> combinations. So the probability of no pair is (13C5)*4<sup>5</sup>/51!